# Messy grounds inside of DeLonghi ESAM 2600

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance, bean-to-cup

I've got a DeLonghi bean-to-cup machine ([ESAM 2600](http://www.delonghi.com/en-int/products/coffee/coffee-makers/bean-to-cup/caffe-corso-esam-2600-0132212096)), which I find decent in overall. But there is one very annoying issue: not all of the grounds make it from the basket into the internal waste bin. Instead, some of them get scattered over the insides and add extra pain to the cleaning procedure. I feel like this misbehaviour first became noticable with age (can't say exactly, but roughly past the third year of its life), and kept slowly worsening.

I can't seem to find much discussion of the problem. Does anyone know about this machine or bean-to-cups more generally, why they'd do it and whether there's a fix?

(...Or maybe they just don't live that long?)

Comment: Hi Ivan, I have no idea of the machine. But just thinking of troubleshooting... Is it possible that the way from basket to bin is getting dirty in time? If this is the case: Maybe you can try to descale that part? Or maybe even try bleaching to get rid of any organic waste? (Be careful as bleach is corrosive and may damage some internal parts of the machine itself.)

Comment: @MTSan: Thanks, that's a good suggestion. Will try to clean it more thoroughly and observe. It doesn't look like it's getting scale though... I'd say, it looks more as if the central module somehow jerks before emptying and scatters some of those grounds.

Comment: Jerk mostly means not enough grease (or alternatively, a lot of dirt) in between the gears. In the former case, find a way to add some grease. In the latter, find a way to remove the gears, clean them, install them again, and then add some grease. Both of the ways may not be easy, though. Also, please still keep in mind that I'm troubleshooting by "general advice" here. I have no idea of the machine or how you can handle all these advice. :)

Comment: I have exactly this machine, mine does it too. I've had Gaggia machines that do it also. I just vacuum it out with a hand sized vacuum cleaner once in a while.